How to reset settings of visual studio 2017?
I try to open VS 2017 as admin i get this warning :

when i run the command on CMD as administrator i get this error :


There was a patch for this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30178
It's an issue with the C++ runtime.

If you can open the application
first go to the Menu Bar then in Import and Export Settings Wizard and reset all the settings then select Next
Hope its help you

Try to run the VS under safemode using devenv /SafeMode and from there see which extension or setting is messing up with the VS2017
Check logs: %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<Version>\ActivityLog.xml
Also, try the best practice to turn it off and on again:

VS
OS

